# 'cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor'

Tags: c#

I've just started learning c# and have a very basic knowledge of how it all works. I keep getting error code 'CS0154' for the line 'player.HasGravity in this code:

```
using GTA;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GTA.Math;
using GTA.Native;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class SuperJump : Script
{
    public SuperJump()
    {
        Tick += OnTick;
        KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
        KeyUp += OnKeyUp;
        Interval = 10;
    }

    void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            Ped player = Game.Player.Character;
            player.HasGravity
        }
    }
}
```

The error message is:

> The property or indexer 'Entity.HasGravity' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor'.

I've looked some posts with similar problems but I still don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: *Sounds like* `HasGravity` is a property with no getter.  You didnt include that code so it is a guess.

Comment: Really counterintuitive to have a property Has.... and then cannot read from it. Where is the code of this Ped class?

Answer (score 1):

Check your Character class. It is most likely that HasGravity property does not have a get method defined, like so

```
class Character
{
    private bool hasGravity;
    public  bool HasGravity
    {
        set { hasGravity = value; }
    }
}
```

You need to do the following to fix your problem:

```
class Character
{
    private bool hasGravity;
    public  bool HasGravity
    {
        set { hasGravity = value; }
        get { return hasGravity;  }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't use auto-implemented property?

Comment: I could, but the question presupposes that he implemented the setter but not the getter, so most likely he did not use the auto-implemented property.